# Searching for a range efficiently on a sorted Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to search values within a range in a sorted column of Pandas dataframe, in other words, a sorted Series. There are millions of rows so performance matters and I want to use binary search to reduce the complexity.

The first problem is with `Pandas.Series.searchsorted(value)`, I cannot tell if the value actually exists in the series.
e.g.:

```
>>x = pds.Series([1,2,3])
>>x.searchsorted(1) -> return 0
>>x.searchsorted(-1) -> return 0
```

How can I tell if the value actually exists in the series with this function?

The second problem is searching for a range. I'd prefer something like `Pandas.Series.searchsorted(range)` to return the first index of the value within the range.

Is there any packages can help? I am considering writing my own binary search functions but I do not want to ruin the performance advantage of Pandas/numpy. Is diving into Cython my only choice?

Comment: What do you mean a `range`? Something like `[2, 5]`?

Comment: @Psidom Yes, like [2, 5]. As I imagine it will be a binary search on the left and right bound of the range.

Comment: How would you define *within the range*? Left inclusive, right inclusive or both?

Answer (score 2):

To check if a value exists in the *Series*, you can get the value at the returned index and check if they are equal:

```
x = pd.Series([1,2,3])

# value doesn't exist
value = 0.5
x.iat[x.searchsorted(value)[0]] == value
# False

# value exists
value = 1
x.iat[x.searchsorted(value)[0]] == value
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

The `searchsorted` method finds where your value should be inserted to maintain the order of your Series, so it is normal that both `x.searchsorted(1)` and `x.searchsorted(-1)` returns `0`

What you can do to test if your `Series` contains a specific value is to transform it into a `numpy array` or a `list`.

```
1 in list(x)
1 in np.array(x)
```

The first line seems to return faster results.

As for your second problem, I can't find a good solution for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem I think I found a simple solution for you. Lets say you have a range where the minimum value is x1 and the maximum value is x2. So inorder to find the index of the first value in the data series that exist within this range you do the following:

```
x = pd.Series([1,2,3,7,8,9]) # series first_index = -1 # first index of value

x1 = 8, x2 = 10 
index = x.searchsorted(x1) 
if x.iat[[index]] >= x1 and x.iat[[index]] <= x2:
# true, just use index which is 4 
first_index = index

x1 = 4, x2 = 6  
index = x.searchsorted(x1) 
if x.iat[[index]] >= x1 and x.iat[[index]] <= x2:
# false, as 4 < 7 and 7 > 6 so first_index stays -1
```

I hope I answered your second question. No need for other packages or writing your own function!